# Hibernate Validator with Hibernate Dynamic Models (No Entity Class)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I'm using hibernate dynamic models to create a CRUD. I'm wondering how can I validate the http request (@Valid) annotation because I don't have the any entity or DTO.

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
public ResponseEntity<RestResponse> signup(@Valid @RequestBody Map<String, Object> user) {
    var restResponse = new RestResponse<>();

    restResponse.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    restResponse.setResponse(user);

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .body(restResponse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't because there is no java class that for bean validation annotations to put on and that is the sole basis for bean validation. Maybe you should switch to a proper class based model which will also make it easier to understand and debug your application